# MS Project - Column with formula does not calculate correctly

Tags: formula, ms-project

I am trying to add an indicator light to my MS Project sheet similar to this one: [Late Indicator Tool](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tech-decision-maker/add-the-late-indicator-tool-in-microsoft-project-2007/). I'm using a simplified formula: `IIf([% Complete]<>100,DateDiff("d",[Deadline],[Finish]))`

For any row that I enter all the information by hand, the formula works perfectly. However, the formula returns **0** for any rows where I paste data in from other project files (even if all I paste in is the task name).

Even if I attempt to use an even simpler formula (`[Deadline]-[Finish]`), it still returns **0** (and breaks even further by returning **4294925695.29** or **4294925708.67** instead of **#Error** in the rows where the Deadline is **NA**).

Has anyone else had any issues with calculated columns in MS Project and can help me fix it?

**EDIT:** I gave up on this approach when I discovered a work-around: There is a column called "Finish Variance" that will automatically calculate the difference between the Finish date and the date in the "Baseline Finish" column (which I am now using instead of "Deadline").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem sounds like your project may be corrupted (or the file that you are pasting from). I suggest building a small sample project to see if you can replicate this error. (I could not replicate it.)

As for the second problem, when the Deadline is NA, Project is substituting a default value of the largest unsigned 32-bit integer (2^32-1). To avoid this unintended value, use an If statement in your formula to return your own value in case Deadline is NA.

Comment: The problem seems to be compatibility; some people in the office have Project 2003, some have Project 2010, and some have Project 2013. We save all files in 2003 format so that everyone can use them. I had a colleague recreate my file in 2013 and it worked fine, but then fell apart when they saved it in 2003 format.